# Configuring a Postfix backup server

Tags: postfix, smtp, backup

I have a subdomain `subdomain.mydomain` with two servers `server1.subdomain.mydomain` and `server2.subdomain.mydomain` running CentOS 5.5. `server1` runs a Postfix server for `subdomain.mydomain` that acts as a second level SMTP server, i.e., it does relay through another server `relay.mydomain` (on a higher level domain `mydomain`).

I need to set up another Postfix on `server2` to act as a backup server for `server1`, so that `server2` relays to `server1` all mail sent through `server2`.

I have been digging through the Postfix documentation site and found a section named [Configuring Postfix as primary or backup MX host for a remote site](http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html#backup), but it is too brief and not very clear.

**How can I set up the Postfix service on `server2` to relay to/backup `server1`?**

What I have understood from the previous link to Postfix documentation is that I have to set up the following:

On `server1` (main server)

- `relay_domains` must be equal to `relay.mydomain`
- `transport_maps` must be equal to `hash:/etc/postfix/transport`
- `/etc/postfix/transport` must contain the line `subdomaing.mydomain relay:[relay.mydomain]` (and brackets are mandatory for Postfix not to perform MX lookup)

On `server2` (backup server)

- `subdomain.mydomain` must not be listed in `mydestination`
- `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` must be equal to `permit_mynetworks reject_unauth_destination`
- `relay_recipient_maps` must be equal to `hash:/etc/postfix/relay_recipients`
- `/etc/postfix/relay_recipients` must contain a line of the form `user@subdomain.mydomain x` for every mailbox `user` in the system

However, this does not work. When I  start the Postfix server on `server2` and connect using telnet, Postfix does not send any message (no welcome message and no response to any command).

Answer (score 1):

If server2 is a backup to server1, why do you want it relaying messages to server1?  The point of a backup is to provide service if the primary is down.  So if server1 is down, server2 still needs to deliver.

For just a basic backup, server2 could be configured identically to server1.  Then just create an MX record for server2, with server1's MX having a preference of 10 and server2's having a preference of 20.

Comment: I pressumed that `server2` should not store any of the messages, but send them to `server1` to be stored on `server1`. For example, if `server1` is down and `user2@subdomain.mydomain` send an e-mail to `user1@subdomain.mydomain`, that e-mail should be relayed from `server2` to `server1` as soon as `server1` is up again, but should not be stored on a mailbox in `server2`. I do not know if my solution behaves that way, but relaying was the only idea I had, and it is what I understood from the link I put above.